# How to create mod_rewrite for 1 or 2 parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my code this

```
www.test.com/index.php?A=1&B=123
```

I use this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html index.php?A=$1&B=$2
```

Output : www.test.com/1/123.html

OK it working on 2 parameter

Problem : Some time my website have 1 parameter

```
www.test.com/index.php?A=1
```

I want output this :  www.test.com/1.html

How to create RewriteRule  for 1 or 2 parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 different rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html$ index.php?A=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?A=$1&B=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: RewriteRule column1  working   
but RewriteRule column2  Not working

Comment: I test echo $_GET A and B.
Result if 1 parameter : A=1 B="" ok working  , If 2 parameter :A=1/123 B=""   It not working

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.